# Matrix initialization in Android?

Tags: android, matrix, initialization

I'm tring to do a simple matrix initialization in android and I get Error:   `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I'm trying this:

```
 Integer id = Integer.valueOf(idcateg);

            System.out.println("Id-ul e"+id);
            vot = new Integer[sirid.length][id];
            for (int i = 0; i < sirid.length; i++) {
                vot[i][id] = 0;

            }
 where id is a value between 1 and 5,sirid.length is a number that reflects number of images from different categorys. For example,I want for category 1 to have something like this :


 vot[0][1]=0;
   vot[1][1]=0;
   vot[2][1]=0;
```

...etc

Where is my mistache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Integer id = Integer.valueOf(idcateg);

System.out.println("Id-ul e"+id);
vot = new Integer[sirid.length][id];
for (int i = 0; i < sirid.length; i++) {
     vot[i][id-1] = 0;
}
```

array index start from 0

you set the size of the vot array to sirid.lengh by id but the array start index value from 0 to (size)(size value not included) see the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I think because you initialize the array on id. 
After that you call to vot[i][id] which then will alway be 1 too high.

f.e.

if you create new int[3][3]

you can only call positions 0,1 and 2

good luck

Answer (score 0):

That is because `id` has been considered as Length of the String and you r trying to access the same element... but the last element is `vat[i][id-1]` but u r trying to get `vat[i][id]`

So better use this..

```
for (int i = 0; i < sirid.length; i++) {
for(int j = 0; j<id ; j++){
                vot[i][j] = 0;

            }
}
```